# Android public library resource not resolved

Tags: android, string, resources, private, public

In a library com.example.mylibrary I have this strings.xml file:

```
<resources>
    <string name="cde_test_private">This is a private string</string>
    <public type="string" name="cde_test_public">this is a public string</public>
</resources>
```

I succesfully import com.example.mylibrary in My APP com.example.myapp via MavenLocal, ad I set *android.nonTransitiveRClass=false* in *gradle.properties* , so I can succesfully use the resource of com.example.mylibrary in com.example.mylibrary.

Anyway for these strings something don't work:
For cde_test_private all is OK, I see it but I correctly cannot use it:
[image]

But I cannot acces to cde_test_public:

[image]

It seems that it's not resolved\imported.

What's wrong?
How in the same strings.xml can I mark strings for external use or not?